# @Query in Room with TypeConverter

Tags: android, mysql, kotlin, android-room, typeconverter

Hi i use room with typeconverter it works perfectly

```
@Entity(tableName = "Library")
data class Library(@PrimaryKey var id : String,var categories: List<String> = listOf())
```

typeconverter

```
@TypeConverters
object LibraryConverters{
   @TypeConverter
   fun fromString(s : String) : List<String> = Gson().fromJson(s,object : TypeToken<List<String>>() 
                  {}.type)
   @TypeConverter
   fun toJson(l : List<String>) : String = Gson().toJson(l)
}
```

dao

```
@Dao
interface LibraryDao{
  @Query("Select * from Library")
  fun allPaged() : androidx.paging.DataSource.Factory<Int,Library>
  }
```

now i search anyway get all just for one category. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in room my list is saved as just json string and i can get all for one category name with

```
@Dao
interface LibraryDao{
@Query("select * from Library where categories like '%'|| :c ||'%'")
fun all(c : String) : LiveData<List<Library>> 
}
```